# Visual Studio Project with Only Arbritary Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-project

I have an old Perl web site which I need to maintain, and I want to use Visual Studio do to this (mainly to take advantage of the TFS source control integration).

How can I create a project file (similar to .csproj) which will work with the files from my web site, without any of the usual stuff like build and compilation? I just want the source treated as plain text files, for ease of editing and source control.

Comment: You can open a folder with visual studio

Comment: @zerocukor287 That's an interesting idea. However, I want the ability to hide files/folders that I don't want to appear in solution explorer. Also, it doesn't seem to show the source control status in solution explorer when opening as a folder.

Comment: Basically, I use git as a version control, and if the folder is under version control, it shows the status. I don't know if this trick can be utilized with tfvc.

Comment: For the hide/show thing, I've found this documentation. There is a section 'Create project from existing code'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2022   Also, you can create an empty solution and add files to it.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richterger.perl

Comment: Adding files at the solution level is what the previous developer left me. It's clunky because I have to add each individual file (whereas with a project, I can include files with wildcards). Unfortunately, "create from existing code" needs a concrete project type, which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the world has moved on from Perl (a language I have used *OO Perl* anyone?) it has also moved on from TFS.

Moving to Git and using an app *more* suited to **folder type projects** such as found with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), instead would be a more future proof way of **handling and maintaining** old source. It avoids issues of trying to *shoe horn* a Perl type project into a project type that it was not designed for...

Creating a git repository to house the code and using VS Code is not a major leap from Visual Studio. Its unclear what is being saved by staying with TFS in an editor not designed for Perl projects.

See [VSCode as a Perl IDE](https://dev.to/perldean/vscode-as-a-perl-ide-3cco)

Comment: At the moment our entire code base is in TFSVC. Moving to git (although potentially advantageous) is simply not in the cards right now. I don't have time for future proofing legacy systems - I just need to fix the bugs and get back to my real job :)

Comment: A different version of code debt, gotcha. I contracted for a company that it took 30 years before they migrated a punch card based program to something more 21st century. :-/ To quote Captain Kirk in `Mirror Mirror` to the evil Spock, *"In every revolution there's one man with a vision."* :-)